# How can I get the page layout to stop disappearing momentarily when accessing a non-existent page in Blazor?

Tags: .net-core, blazor, webassembly

I have setup a page to display when the user enters a URL that does not correspond to a page in my Blazor project.  The content is defined in App.razor:

```
            <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>There is nothing at this address.</p>
                <img src="/images/broken_wine_glass.jpg" />
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
```

The problem is that when the user clicks on a link that takes them to an invalid address, the entire layout disappears for a moment before returning along with the "nothing at this address" content.  Is there a way to redirect to this page without the menu in the layout ever disappearing?

Comment: When you say "The user enters a URL that does not..." do you mean enters the URL in the browser URL bar, or into some control in your application. Any URL entered in the browser bar is a hard http get (unless you code to stop it) and will "Reboot" the SPA, which explains the "disappears for a moment".  Blazor Server?  In Blazor WASM, it will be more than a "moment".

Comment: The answer is simple: move to server side Blazor. What you have been seeing is the way the web works. This is natural or at least unavoidable. Just display a message like: Learn to type or something less polite.

Comment: All layout disappear for a moment, this is a normal phenomenon. Is it because the rendering stays for too long during the period?

Comment: @MichaelKossin Hi, it's good to ask a question but you do need to respond??? Or close it if you've figured out the answer.

Comment: @ShaunCurtis, this also happens if the user accesses a non-existent page by clicking on a link in the application.

Comment: @MichaelKossin.  Chris has kindly answered below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the reason for this is how Blazor attempts to find a matching route.

First, it will check the local routing table for a component which handles the route. If this fails, it will redirect to the server and see if the server has a matching route. If this fails, the Blazor app is reloaded and the not found template on the router is rendered.

The flicker you're describing occurs when the app is reloaded during the above process.

Comment: It's good to know why this happens.  Thank you.